# Print variables after being redirected

Tags: php

I have a register form that upon being completed and validated, it will redirect the user to a page/file where I want to tell him something like

```
Thank you for registering, ' . $name_register . '. You may login using the form to the left using your username ' . $username_register . ' and your password
```

How can I pass the variables to my other file?

Comment: put those in redirecting url as `attribute=value` or use session variable to check whether registration is success or not

Comment: But I want only users who have registered to have access to this script/page.

Comment: You can also use sessions which is transferrable across many pages.

Comment: how can you know that user is same without loggin in?

Comment: Why don't you just login the user in? (;

Comment: Later on I may add email verification. That would still require me to tell them something like "check your email $emailname for verification code"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To store variables in client(browser) side, best thing is Session. Just set the session and use it later whenever you want to.

//Set data in session 
**$_SESSION['name_register']="Miral Viroja";**

//Retrieve data from session
**echo "Welcome Mr ". $_SESSION['name_register'];**

Comment: Should I open sessions for all users? I mean, should I do it even for people that aren't logged in?

Comment: Yes you can. There is no problem to set the session with another variable rather than logged user.